# Change base language of vuetify UI components

Tags: vuetify.js

For example : [image]
Shown in the documentation : [Vuetify documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#data-table)

We have the "Items per page" displayed in english. If i want to change the text or just select the language to translate it to french for instance, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Despite not being explicitly mentioned the `locale` prop seems to be present in all the vuetify components so you can use it. See my example.

src/components/my-datatable.vue

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    locale="fr"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>
```

src/plugins/vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

import fr from 'vuetify/src/locale/fr.ts'

Vue.component('my-component', {
  methods: {
    changeLocale () {
      this.$vuetify.lang.current = 'fr'
    },
  },
})

export default new Vuetify({
  lang: {
    locales: { fr },
    current: 'fr',
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<v-data-table :rows-per-page-items="rowOptions" :rows-per-page-text="rowPageText">           
</v-data-table>
```

```
data () {
   return {
       rowOptions: [
            5,
            15,
            25,
            { text: "$vuetify.dataIterator.rowsPerPageAll", value: -1 }
        ],
        rowPageText: "Objets par page:"
    }
}
```

Or you may want to check the  [internationalization documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/internationalization#internationalization)

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer => 2022

if you are like me and don't want to set up internationalization in vuetify's config, do this instead:

(note: I have set up @nuxtjs/i18n and have access to 'this.$t()' throughout my application. you can freely use any other text instead of them.)

for headers it's easy:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
>

 data() {     
   headers: [
     { text: this.$t('id'), value: 'id' },
     { text: this.$t('status'), value: 'state' },
     { text: this.$t('title'), value: 'title' },
     { text: this.$t('price'), value: 'amount' },
     { text: this.$t('date'), value: 'time' },
     { text: this.$t('gateway'), value: 'gateway' },
   ]
 }
```

and for footer props:

```
<v-data-table
  :footer-props="footerProps"
>

data() {
  footerProps: {
      disableItemsPerPage: true,
      itemsPerPageText: this.$t('itemsPerPageText'),
      itemsPerPageAllText: this.$t('all'),
  }
}
```

this was enough for me cause my table was rather simple.

for more footer props refer to the documentation:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-footer/#props